# Where is the 'Edit Review' template located in Magento admin?

Tags: magento-1.5, magento-1.7, magento

I want to add an extra field in 'edit review' in Magento admin. Where is the 'Edit Review' template located in Magento (path of the file)? or which file does the editing of reviews in Magento admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block class that handles this is called `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Edit_Form`. You'll resolve its location from the class name.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the example code you are looking for can be found here:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Edit/Form.php
```

Assuming, of course, that you have a default installation.